# How can I improve my Windows Batch File that merges two PDFs into a separate folder to move the PDF regardless of whether a merge exists

Tags: batch-file, pdf, merge, command

I have a windows batch file that merges PDFs from two separate folders and dumps them into a 3rd folder. One of the PDFs is a PDF of a map survey and the other are any accompanying photos the surveyor took. As of now the batch file only moves files that it is able to merge, but I'd want the first page map survey to move to the other folder regardless of whether it has an accompanying photo.

So my question is if I can add a line that moves PDFs from the "sourcemap" directory in my code below regardless of whether "sourcetables" directory has a matching file. Thank you for any help. Here is my code below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "pdftk=C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe"

set "sourcemap=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central"
set "sourcetables=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Photos"
set "destination=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central Completed"

set pdffile=
set pdfattach=
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /o:n "%sourcemap%\*.pdf"') do (
    set "pdffile=%sourcemap%\%%i"
    set "pdfattach=%sourcetables%\PestManagement_TableSeries_!pdffile:~50!"
    set "outputpdf=%%~ni"
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe" "!pdffile!" "!pdfattach!" cat output "%destination%\!pdffile:~50,-4! - Field Scout Survey Map %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.pdf"
    echo "Successfully completed !pdffile:~50,-4!"
)

set "gisfolder=C:\GIS\Maps\Ranch Map Staging Folders\PCA\Central Completed"
set "spfolder=\\sunpacific.local\lerdodata\Sun Pacific Public\6 - Business Units\Sun Pacific Farming Cooperative\B - General\10 - Maps\Ranch Maps\Other Maps\PCA\Maps\Central"
set "archivefolder=\\sunpacific.local\lerdodata\Sun Pacific Public\6 - Business Units\Sun Pacific Farming Cooperative\B - General\10 - Maps\Other Maps\PCA\Old Maps\Central"

move "%spfolder%\*.pdf" "%archivefolder%"

move "%gisfolder%\*.pdf" "%spfolder%"

cmd /k
```

Comment: `if exist "!pdfattach!" (run pdftk) else (move the file.)`

Comment: @Squashman Thank you for your response. I would replace move `move "%spfolder%\*.pdf" "%archivefolder%"` with that correct?